# "Russia. Where is your soul" - shouldn't it be "Russia. Where your soul is"?

Tags: questions, word-order

From [a news report](http://www.e1.ru/news/spool/news_id-430828.html): Russia's Federal Tourism Agency (Rosturizm) held a contest for the development of Russia's tourism logo, and this design took second place:

[image: Poster with wording "Where is your soul"]

Is the wording here felicitous? It seems to me that it might imply that Russia lacks a soul, if read as a [rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question). Say, "What on Earth has happened to your soul, Russia? Where is it?"

Shouldn't it be instead

> Russia. Where your soul is.

.. or is it really okay? I'm at a loss because I presume there are plenty of people at Rosturizm who are fluent in English. There has to be a professional linguist on the contest's committee, since the logo's intended target audience is (English-speaking) foreigners.

Comment: I read it like you... but let the native speakers chime in.

Comment: I agree with you about the word order ("Where your soul is" is better); however, in my humble opinion, I believe that the logo won the prize because of the design.(The idea of Saint Basil's Cathedral + P + R + <3 = the logo is really neat. I love it!)

Comment: @DamkerngT. - I see. Probably it was impossible to change the wording post-submission. I don't understand what do the letters P+R mean. "Public Relations"? (0:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is it probably was supposed to be "Here is your soul" (with inversion) rather than "(W)here is your soul", though the former variant sounds a bit awkward too (and has a different meaning).

According to the author's vk page ([Andrew Efanov](http://vk.com/id8382052)), the very first variant of the logo read "Your soul is here" which is perfectly correct:

[image]

and so is the final variant, present at the [official page](http://www.russiatourism.ru/news/9082/) of the contest:

[image]

As to "P + R" letters, well it has to do with the resemblance between the Latin letter "**R**" (that starts the word "**R**ussia") and Cyrillic letters "Р" and "Я" (that start and end the word "**Р**осси**Я**"). You can see them all in the logo.

Comment: I suppose it should be obvious from the context, but "Россия" translates to "Russia".  I'm curious, which is the correct character to use in that word, и or и́?  Searching the web I see both used.

Comment: @John Well, spelling "Росси́я" just shows you the place of the stress (on the second syllable, that is "РоссИя", not "РОссия"), while the normal spelling is one and only: "Россия".

Answer (score 1):

The original page is in Russian so I cannot make out what is the purpose of this advertisement. But looking at the placement of words in the logo, there are two possibilities.

**If you want to make it a question,** (in case Russia ***lacks*** the soul), what all it requires is the question mark - *'?'*

> Russia 
>  Where **is** *your (Russia's)* soul?

If you want to emphasize that **Russia is the place where your soul is**, it may go as you suggested...

> **Russia** 
>  Where *your (reader's)* soul **is**

Comment: I read it just the other way round - I don't "need" the '?' to understand this as a question. I'm pretty sure what the advertiser really meant was *Russia - the place where your soul is". And even with the eclipse of "the place" word order should remain unchanged.